# domain is pointing to default static page on server but settings look correct

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have edited my apache vhost file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` to add the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mysite.cn
ServerAlias mysite.cn *.mysite.cn
DocumentRoot /home/user/static/mysite/cn
</VirtualHost>
```

It still points to the default site on the server when i browse to `mysite.cn` but when i enter anything along the lines of `ww3.mysite.cn` it point to the new correct document root any clues of what the problem could be as i am lost.

Comment: Please provide output to the following command:
**grep ^[^#] "location of httpd.conf"**

Comment: The location of httpd.conf is /etc/apache2/ nothing is served out this file.All vhost setting are stored in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/

Comment: Are you sure `mysite.cn` and `ww3.mysite.cn` all resolve to IP addresses assigned to this server?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz its pointing to the correct ip for this server, dns records are all correct and this server only has ip assigned to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong page is cached somewhere; depending on the somewhere try these things:

- Apache: sudo apache2ctl restart
- Your web browser: close and restart, perhaps delete cached files, or try another browser
- Your local computer DNS settings: flush your DNS cache ([first Google link](http://kb.liquidweb.com/flush-dns-cache/))

For obvious performance reasons, both your web browser and your apache server are very dedicated to caching things.